# how i can rotate an object by a specified angle in python or jypiter notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, 2d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQPrQ.png)

I need to rotate object in python with this formula  ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7G8i.png))

```
rotate an object by a specified angle.
```

Comment: It seems like you link there tells you exactly what to do. What is your question?

Comment: Please consider [adding code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate an object, you are just changing the coordinates of the vertices.

You can do this using matrix multiplication:

```py
import numpy as np

theta = np.radians(int(input("How many radians? ")))
c,s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta) #get sin and cosine of the angle

rotate = np.array(((c, -s), (s,c))) #put them into the rotation matrix


shape = np.array(((0,0))) #put the coordinates that you would like to rotate
print(f'new coords = {np.matmul(rotate,shape)}') #output
```

This takes the radians as an input and then rotates the coordinate.
If you wanted to do the repeatedly on an object with multiple vertices (and therefore coordinates) you could iterate the calculation and append the new coordinates into an array:

```py
import numpy as np

theta = np.radians(int(input("How many radians? ")))

number_of_coords = int(input("How many coordinates? "))

result = []

for i in range(number_of_coords):
    c,s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta) #get sin and cosin of the angle
    rotate = np.array(((c, -s), (s,c))) #put them into the rotation matrix

    for l in range(2):
        x = int(input("what is the first number? "))
        y = int(input("what is the second input? "))
        coord = (x,y)
        shape = np.array((coord)) 
        result.append(np.matmul(rotate,shape))


print(f"new shape = {result}")
```

This outputs the arrays that then contain the new coordinates

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have a slightly different and need to rotate the object by code based on the formula -    (  ∙ cos −  ∙ sin ,  ∙ sin +  ∙ cos  )

Comment: To get the mutplication to be that way round the only thing you would need to change is the order the matrices is multiplied by. (The additions and subtraction is done in matrix multiplication). ```@George```